# CSS vertical-align center on block or inline-block anchor elements

Tags: css

The menus I am working on are 40px in height and are set to `display: inline-block` in order to make them easier to click on. However I'm having trouble getting the text to vertically align to the middle.

The challenge is to get the text to display using `vertical-align: middle` while also **not** using any `table` related value for the `display` property, that is cheap and I'm trying to determine how to do this affordable.

Here is what I currently have...

**XHTML**

```
<div id="menu">
<div><a class="menu" href="blog/" tabindex="2">Blog</a></div>
<div><a class="menu" href="contact/" tabindex="2">Contact</a></div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu {height: 40px;}
#menu > div {display: block; float: left; height: 100% !important;}
#menu > div > a {color: #fff; height: 40px; display: inline-block !important; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 100px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a `line-height` equal to the box `height` to align it vertically to the middle.

```
#menu > div > a {
    color: #000;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block !important;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 40px; /* added this line */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4H4tJ/)

Comment: @John: Does your menu have items spanning multiple lines? If yes, then this method will get tricky because they will get pushed down. I assumed it was going to be only one line :)

Comment: Yes, only one line...and now I fear that one day I'll need to do a menu with multiple lines, post a question and have some prissy mod come stomping in and claim it's a duplicate question. >__>

Comment: @John: You can use [**this method**](http://jsfiddle.net/4H4tJ/2/) (uses pseudo elements) for vertically centering if the text is in multiple lines. (Note: Use this only if you have atleast one menu item which spans multiple lines)

Comment: Thanks, I use `white-space: nowrap;` on menus though it's a nice bonus that others with the same problem as I may want; I try to go a bit beyond when answering questions too, hopefully you'll get some up-votes for that too. :-)